# How to use multiple inputs in the keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to combine the `four multiple inputs` into the `single` keras model, but it requires `inputs with matching shapes`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
input3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,))
input4 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1, input2, input3, input4])

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2, input3, input4], outputs=x)
```

**Here is the output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_3447/2584043467.py in <cell line: 6>()
      4 input4 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
      5 
----> 6 x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([input1, input2, input3, input4])
      7 
      8 x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/merging/concatenate.py in build(self, input_shape)
    112       ranks = set(len(shape) for shape in shape_set)
    113       if len(ranks) != 1:
--> 114         raise ValueError(err_msg)
    115       # Get the only rank for the set.
    116       (rank,) = ranks

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 28, 28, 1), (None, 28, 28, 3), (None, 128), (None, 1)]
```

How to combine the above `inputs` in the `single` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually telling you what the problem is. All dimensions except the one you want to concatenate have to be the same and they are not. You can try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 3))
input3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,))
input4 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input1)
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(input2)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([input1, input2, input3, input4])

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2, input3, input4], outputs=x)
```

Comment: I want to use four 4 inputs with different shapes, and finally split the training into 4 diff output shapes (the 4 output shape is same as input). Do I need to write a custom layer for this 4 outputs?

Comment: @stackbiz I am a bit confused.. did you not just want to concatenate all inputs into one tensor? Or why are you using the `Concatenate` layer? Your question here does not seem to have anything to do with your original question?

Comment: My purpose is to test the multiple inputs with different shapes, and finally multiple outputs with different shapes. The post example is for testing how to add multiple inputs to the same model. The original Concatenate layer is just an example as I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Ok. I think your original question was answered and I think your next question can only be answered if you provide more details (in a new question) and show what you have tried already.

Comment: I will try how to write multiple outputs shapes in the keras model first. But I have a question about the inputs. Is it the the only way for combining different shapes into the same model is to use `tf.keras.layers.Flatten()`?

Comment: You generally need to make sure that all shapes match except the one you are concatenating on.. It is up to you how you will get those shapes. The most straight-forward way would be to use reshaping / flattening..you can also process your input1 and input2 with CNNs and then flatten + concatenate. It is up to you.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible as I never tried. Can I write a custom layer for accepting 4 different shapes, without flattening first. and then do some logic in the custom layer, and finally output another shapes in the same custom layer?

Comment: Yes definitely..it is all up to you.

Comment: I think I can try to create new layer based on your answer by modifying the Concatenate layer. Thanks for your help.